# How can you make the navbar responsive when using this code?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have tried to get the navbar responsive but somehow it dosen't work. It stays the same way. Do you have any recommendations? I need to use @media.

And also, do you have any tips when doing the existing code responsive, any website etc?

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: #5D4954;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 70%;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a {
    color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transformation: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a.active, a:hover {
    background: black;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

Comment: you have to use  @media query

Comment: Can you share HTML and CSS complete code?

Comment: How can I share my code in here?

Answer (score 0):

I would use @media, along with JS for menu icon that is going to have your navbar when you resize your page.

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgrey ;
}
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#">Test1</a>
<a href="#">Test2</a>
<a href="#">Test3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to try **display flex** if you are not confident about using this. You can use just display none/block and float properties.

Also make sure you are using **ul** and **li** tags for creating nav items.

In responsive page it is mandatory to use below meta tag to render page correctly in mobile devices.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        nav {


            background-color: #5D4954;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        nav ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .logo {
            color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 5px;
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .nav-links {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        .nav-links li {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .nav-links a {
            color: rgb(226, 226, 226);
            text-decoration: none;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 14px;
            border-radius: 3px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        a.active,
        a:hover {
            background: black;
            transition: .5s;
        }

        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
            float: left;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }



        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .topnav li:not(:first-child) {

                display: none;
            }

            .topnav a.icon {
                float: right;
                display: block;
            }

            .topnav.responsive {
                position: relative;
            }


            .topnav.responsive li {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }

            .topnav.responsive .icon {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
            }

            .topnav.responsive a.icon {
                float: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }


        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <ul>
            <li class="nav-links"><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>

            <li class="nav-links"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
            <li class="nav-links"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

            <li class="nav-links"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </nav>

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
        <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
        <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
        <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            if (x.className === "topnav") {
                x.className += " responsive";
            } else {
                x.className = "topnav";
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

using this you can easily make responsive navbar

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu-btn').click(function(event) {
            $('.navbar-demo').toggleClass('open-nav');
        });
    });
```

```css
    body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Roboto;
    }

    .hero-image .about-me {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        right: 0;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    .hero-image .about-me label {
        font-size: 26px;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
    }
    .hero-image:after {
        background-color: black;
        content: '';
         position: absolute; 
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    .hero-image {
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: lightgray;
        background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495465798138-718f86d1a4bc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80');
        display: table;
          background-position: center;
    }


    .hero-image .about-me a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        margin: 20px;
    }


    .navbar-demo {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
    }

    .navbar-demo .nav-bar ul li {
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar-demo .nav-bar ul {
        padding: 0;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar-demo .nav-bar ul li a {
        font-size: 18px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000;
        padding: 18px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .nav-bar {
        text-align: center;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-demo button.menu-btn {
        display:none;
    }







@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
   .navbar-demo  button.menu-btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: unset;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 26px;
        display:block;
        padding: 23px;
        color: #fff;
        outline: none;
    } 
    .navbar-demo{
        height:100%;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    .navbar-demo .nav-bar {
        left: -950px;
        background-color: #000000d9;
        transition: 1s;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-demo.open-nav  .nav-bar{
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        transition: left 0.5s;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .navbar-demo .nav-bar ul li a {
         display: block;
         color: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-demo.open-nav button.menu-btn i:before {
        content: '\f00d ';
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Meta View Port -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  


<header id="header" class="navbar-demo">
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Gallery</a>
                <a href="#">About Me</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    <button type="" class="menu-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</header> 

<div class="hero-image">
    <div class="about-me">
        <div class="row">
            <label>My Name is John Doe</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```